# Collation conflicts between views and functions when using utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation

Tags: mariadb, functions, view

Currently running MariaDB 10.3.24 and I really want to fully support the utf8mb4 unicode character set in my databases.

The problem I am running into is that when I try and set everything up to use the utf8mb4 character set and set all collation references to utf8mb4_unicode_ci I then have problems with views that have functions in them .... getting "collation mismatch" error on some but not all comparisons, e.g. this != that or this = that, etc. If I then set all the collation references back to utf8mb4_general_ci then all is fine ..... Is there something that I am doing wrong or is there some sort of work around that I have to do when creating views and functions when using the utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation ....

Thanks

Comment: Can you create [some minimal examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3)? [MDEV-13981](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13981) seems to be one of the few upstream bugs related to utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Answer (score 0):

Before defining Stored Routines, etc, establish the desired `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION`.  One way to do that is via `SET NAMES`.

Also check

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE
```

`utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is newer than `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.  (I don't know what collation changes were made by Unicode between their 4.0.0 and 5.2.0 versions.  You may never notice a difference.)